# How to overcome this error:- Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following method:-

```
public void AssignGroupRole(int id, int[] selectedGroups, int[] currentGroups)
        {
            var roleGroups = FindRole(id).Groups;
            var roleGroupsCopy = roleGroups;
            var securityRole = FindRole(id);
            foreach (var group in roleGroupsCopy)
            {
                if (currentGroups != null)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < currentGroups.Count(); c++)
                    {
                        if (group.GroupID == currentGroups[c])
                        {

                            securityRole.Groups.Remove(group);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

But i am receiving an  error  "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." on

```
foreach (var group in roleGroupsCopy)
```

ay advice on how i can overcome this error ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
foreach (var group in roleGroupsCopy.ToList())
```

Calling ToList() copies it to a temp list that you loop over. The temporary list will not be modified.

An alternative is to use:

```
securityRole.Groups.RemoveAll(g => g.GroupID == currentGroups[c]);
```

Comment: You don't even need roleGroupsCopy. Just use roleGroups.ToList().

Answer (score 2):

Use `for` loop instead of `foreach`. Please see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

It states:

> The foreach statement is used to iterate through the collection to get
>   the desired information, but should not be used to change the contents
>   of the collection to avoid unpredictable side effects.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but why ti should use loop instead? and what is causing this error?

Comment: See edit, somewhere your _roleGroupsCopy_ is being modified that gave this error.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but my roleGroupsCopy is not being modified any where i am just iterating over it ?

Comment: @johnG: You are modifying it, because `securityRole.Groups == roleGroupsCopy == roleGroups`. These are just three references ("pointers") to the same collection and not copies of the collection.

Comment: Here the term _modification_ also includes _elements removal_. This line modifies _roleGroupsCopy_ collection: _securityRole.Groups.Remove(group);_ since _roleGroupsCopy = securityRole.Groups_